# Difference between types {}, object, Object typscript

Tags: typescript

I don’t understand what the types of {} object are for. Object in typescript.

I will show three options. Please explain to me that they can get x, y, z ?.

```
const x: object | { x: number } = ?; // What can accept x and why ?
const y: Object | { y: number } = ?; // What can accept y and why ?
const z: {} | { z: number } = ?; // What can accept z and why ?
```

I am new and it’s very difficult for me to understand all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation states](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html) that:

> Don’t ever use the types `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Symbol`, or `Object`. These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code.

So the uppercase `Object` is not something you would commonly use.

A variable of type `object` can be assigned any value whose type evaluates to `object` (e.g. object literals, arrays, instances of complex types). See the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) function.

`{}` is an object without any properties but also without explicit type. You can e.g. assign a string to this, which is not the case for `object`.

---

As for your code, you define the variables as union types using `|`, so you can always assign values of either the left or the right type. Note that additional properties are always allowed here.